# Why TwoFactorMethodsInfo is not accessible?

Tags: apex, sobject

I want to run a SOQL query on this object `TwoFactorMethodsInfo`. Yet by some reason it is not supported:

[image]

This documentation references it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_passwordless_login_in_apex.htm

So why it is not supported?

Comment: Have you [*enabled* 2FA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_2fa_config.htm&type=5)? You can't typically query an object if its related feature is not enabled.

Comment: No, I haven't. As long as I understand it correctly, 2FA can be enabled through permissions or profile settings by the admin. Or is there a switch that turns on 2FA as a feature which then can be used on profiles?

Comment: This object seems to work only in context of Apex (not even in anonymous window). As an example I tried this query in a test class and was able to save and run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in API permission to access this object. (Note that multi-factor authentication was formerly called two-factor authentication.)